# Сузить ширину колонки при удержание мыши?

Tags: vue.js

Я реализовал чтобы при удержании мыши расширять ширину столбца, но вот как сужать расстояние, пока что не понятно мне

```js
let columns = [
  { name: "name", label: "Name" },
  { name: "last_name", label: "Last Name" },
  { name: "phone", label: "Phone" },
  { name: "email", label: "Email" },  
]

let rows = [
  { name: "Ivan", last_name: "Ivanov", phone: "8999999", email: "test@test.ru" },
 { name: "Ivan", last_name: "Ivanov", phone: "8999999", email: "test@test.ru" },
 { name: "Ivan", last_name: "Ivanov", phone: "8999999", email: "test@test.ru" },
]
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    columns: columns,
    rows: rows,
    draggable: false,
    width: 100
  },
  methods: {
   move(e) {
      if (this.draggable) {
        this.width = this.width + e.offsetX;
      }
    },
    startMove(e) {
      this.draggable = true;
    },
    stopMove() {
      this.draggable = false;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopMove);
  }
})
```

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="body">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td v-for="column in columns" :style="{ position: 'relative', width: width + 'px' }">
        {{ column.label }}
        <div
             style="
                    cursor: col-resize;
                    right: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 5px;
                    bottom: 0;"
             @mousemove="move"
             @mousedown="startMove"
             ></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="row in rows">
        <td v-for="column in columns">{{ row[column.name] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let columns = [
  { name: "name", label: "Name", width: 100 },
  { name: "last_name", label: "Last Name", width: 100 },
  { name: "phone", label: "Phone", width: 100 },
  { name: "email", label: "Email", width: 100 },  
]

let rows = [
  { name: "Ivan", last_name: "Ivanov", phone: "8999999", email: "test@test.ru" },
 { name: "Ivan", last_name: "Ivanov", phone: "8999999", email: "test@test.ru" },
 { name: "Ivan", last_name: "Ivanov", phone: "8999999", email: "test@test.ru" },
]
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    columns: columns,
    rows: rows,
    draggable: false,
    startOffset: 0,
    selectedCol: null
  },
  methods: {
   move(e) {
      if (this.draggable) {
        let newWidth = this.startOffset + e.pageX;
        let colObj = this.columns[this.selectedCol];
        colObj.width = newWidth;
        this.$set(this.columns, this.selectedCol, colObj)
      }
    },
    startMove(e, ind) {
      this.draggable = true;
      this.startOffset = this.columns[ind].width - e.pageX;
      this.selectedCol = ind;
    },
    stopMove() {
      this.draggable = false;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopMove);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.move);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopMove);
   document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.stopMove);
  }
})
```

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="body">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td v-for="(column, ind) in columns" :style="{ position: 'relative', width: column.width + 'px' }">
        {{ column.label }}
        <div
             style="
                    cursor: col-resize;
                    right: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 5px;
                    bottom: 0;"
             @mousedown="startMove($event, ind)"
             ></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="row in rows">
        <td v-for="column in columns">{{ row[column.name] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
```